# android app does not return to its previous screen when i exit the app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an app with 3 activity.

1.Main Activity
2.Registration Screen
3.Registration Success Screen

About my app:
My manifest would load the main activity on launch.
Under my main activity, i would direct it to the registration screen.
Once user fill in their particular, it will direct to the registration success screen.

Scenario:
During my test, after filling in the the particular and moving to the registration screen, whenever i press the menu button (hardware button on the phone), to either answer a phone call or check other things. I when i click on my app icon, i would be directed back to the registration screen instead of the registration success screen.

How i tackle it and it fail:
Under `Onstop()`, i would save a int pagenumber.
For example for the registration screen, once `onstop()`, i would assign `pagenumber = 2`
and for registration success, `onstop()`, i would assign `pagenumber =3`

Under my main activity,
`if(pagenumber == 2)`, i would load registration screen
`if(pagenumber == 3)`, i would load registration success screen

Unfortunately this method does not work, would appreciate if you could provide solutions and feedback on my solution.

Comment: I see, it seems you may need to implement Bundles and Saved Instances properly, can you post you codes for the 3 activities?

Comment: I wouldn't handle it with some member variables but check if I have stored some registration values. If that is the case, I would continue to the what ever will be shown after the success screen...

Comment: Please post your manifest file and you said that "moving to the registration screen, you press menu button". When you re-open app, it comes to registration screen. If you press home button from registration screen, it will come back to registration screen only

Answer (score 0):

In the 3rd activity "registration success screen" you need to handle the onResume() event and in that you need to call the finish() function. Then it will automatically goes back to registration screen once you resume your application

FLOW :

Activity1 ->Activity2 ->Activity3

scenario is when you are in activity3 you go to other application and when you resume to your application activity3 will be in active so you need to call finish() in onResume() of activity3 then it will go to Activity2 from activity3.